# Can I spread Shingles to other parts of my own body?

Tags: herpes, shingles

I've got shingles. Yuck. It is possible for me to accidentally spread it to other parts of my own body? If the virus is on my fingers (from touching the blisters, I suppose) and I touch my eye, could it spread to my eye and make me go blind? If I touch my genitals, could I give myself genital herpes? These sound like really stupid questions written down but I don't want to take any chances.